# How to join a table with many rows to a table with only one row without any duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble where my INNER JOIN duplicates data. I have a fault table and a media table which stores image filepaths.

---

Table 1: fault

Table 2: media

A user uploads their fault into table: fault, and then up to 7 images to support their application in to table: media. At present when 5 images say are uploaded, the fault data is repeated 5 times.

---

```
SELECT * FROM fault INNER JOIN media ON media.syncReportID = fault.faultID where faultID = {0}
```

This is ok but when you inner join something, everything is returned for every item in the joined table.

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500644/inner-join-without-duplicates-is-it-possible) suggests: DISTINCT- I get no exception but it does not work for me.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM fault INNER JOIN media ON media.syncReportID = fault.faultID where faultID = {0}
```

This SO article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769641/left-join-without-duplicate-rows-from-left-table) suggets: `OUTER APPLY` and `GROUP BY` but being honest I do not understand the complex syntax in these articles.

Can someone advise which SQL command would best suit the ability to allow many images to one story without duplicating the story many times over.

Is this even possible here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected result?

Comment: Uh, what table has duplicates?  What table doesn't?  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I have edited my question, sorry for being unclear

Comment: I suspect you want to do 2 separate queries - one to show the fault information, another that gets all the related images. This way you'll always get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want:

```
SELECT f.*, m.*
FROM fault f CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 m.*
      FROM media m
      WHERE m.syncReportID = f.faultID
     ) m
WHERE faultID = {0};
```

You would use `OUTER APPLY` if you always want exactly one row returned, even when there are no matching entries.

Comment: Thanks. This returns just one image though, not all related images

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the fields you want to be distinct 
like :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT fault.faultId,...... FROM fault INNER JOIN media ON media.syncReportID = fault.faultID where faultID = {0}
```